# Typescript compile-time same-type constraint

Tags: typescript, inheritance, compile-time

Here's a short example:

```
abstract class Base {
    private _id: number;

    protected set id(value: number) {
        this._id = value;
    }
    protected get id(): number {
        return this._id;
    }

}

abstract class Mid extends Base {
    equals(another: Mid) {
        if (this.constructor.name !== another.constructor.name) {
            throw TypeError(`Cannot compare ${this.constructor.name} to ${another.constructor.name}`);
        }
        return this.id === another.id;
    }
}

class ChildA extends Mid {
    constructor(public name: string) {
        super();
    }
}
class ChildB extends Mid {
    constructor(public name: string) {
        super();
    }
}

const a = new ChildA('Joe');
const b = new ChildB('John');

a.equals(b); // PREVENT!
```

**What I have**

If you try comparing `ChildA` to `ChildB` it throws a `TypeError`.

**What I want**

I want to statically prevent the use of equals method between different classes. If I am not allowed to compare Apples to Oranges in the source, then I wouldn't need to throw an error at run-time! *(Also one less test to write)*

Note that `Mid` is going to be something very general like `Entity`, while the `Child` classes are going to be something like Customer, Order, etc. - things with business meaning. Makes no sense to compare Customers to Orders, so I wanted to show that in the source via types (after all, that's the whole point of using TypeScript, in my opinion).

**Questions**

1. How can I achieve this?
2. Should I want to achieve this? Maybe I don't need to worry about developers (myself included) doing stupid things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can constrain the parameter to be derived from the type of the variable you are accessing `equal` from:

```
abstract class Mid extends Base {
    equals<T extends this>(another: T) {
        // ...
        return this.id === another.id;
    }
}

class ChildA extends Mid {
    private foo: string;
    constructor(public name: string) {
        super();
    }
}
class ChildAA extends ChildA {
    private foo2: string;
    constructor( name: string) {
        super(name);
    }
}
class ChildB extends Mid {
    private bar: string;
    constructor(public name: string) {
        super();
    }
}

const a = new ChildA('Joe');
const b = new ChildB('John');

a.equals(b); //Error
a.equals(new ChildAA(''));  // Works if you don't want this to work, use equals(another: this)  as the signature instead
```

Since Typescript uses structural typing if `ChildA` and `ChildB` have the same structure the above code will not prevent you from calling `equals` but as soon as `ChildA` and `ChildB` are structurally incompatible, you will get an error.

As to the second part of your question, you should evaluate weather this brings more grief ten benefit, it seems like a good constraint to have but you should see how it works out in practice.